# Multer | keep getting "The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type number "

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file, mongoose, multer

I'm trying to figure out how to upload videos from disk storage onto MongoDB using Multer but I keep getting "The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type number".

If somebody could help guide me onto the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated!

**Storage and Storage Upload**

```
const uploadStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb)=> {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb)=> {
        cb(null, Date.now(), + ' - ' + file.originalname)
    }
})

const storageUpload = multer({
    storage: uploadStorage
})
```

**Post route**

```
app.post('/upload', storageUpload.single('videoUpload'), (req, res) => {
    const newVideoUpload = new uploadMongo({
        video: {
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.file.filename)),
            contentType: 'video/mp4'
        }
    })

    newVideoUpload.save((err, data)=> {
        if(err) {
            throw err
        } else {
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    })
})
```

**MongoDB Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const uploadSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    video: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
}, {timestamps: true})

const uploadModel = mongoose.model('video', uploadSchema)
module.exports = uploadModel;
```

***html page***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Upload a video</h3>
        <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="videoUpload">
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

***Bug***

```
node:internal/validators:129
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type number (1623854458960)
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:129:11)
    at Object.join (node:path:397:7)
    at C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\website\node_modules\multer\storage\disk.js:37:28
    at DiskStorage.filename [as getFilename] (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\website\server.js:26:9)
    at C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\website\node_modules\multer\storage\disk.js:34:10
    at DiskStorage.destination [as getDestination] (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\website\server.js:23:9)
    at DiskStorage._handleFile (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\website\node_modules\multer\storage\disk.js:31:8)
    at C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\website\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:144:17
    at allowAll (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\website\node_modules\multer\index.js:8:3)
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\website\node_modules\multer\index.js:44:7)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\website\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)       
    at Busboy.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\website\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\website\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.emit (node:events:369:20) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from here:

> cb(null, Date.now(), + ' - ' + file.originalname)

The extra `,` is causing the `Date.now()` to be passed as the filename without the string operators. `Date.now()` returns a number.

Try:

```
cb(null, String(Date.now()), + ' - ' + file.originalname)
```

Or

```
cb(null, Date.now() + ' - ' + file.originalname)
```